# how to set different PYTHONPATH variables for python3 and python2 respectively

Tags: python, pythonpath

I want to add a specific library path only to python2. After adding `export PYTHONPATH="/path/to/lib/"` to my `.bashrc`, however, executing python3 gets the error: Your PYTHONPATH points to a site-packages dir for Python 2.x but you are running Python 3.x!

I think it is due to that python2 and python3 share the common `PYTHONPATH` variable.

So, can I set different `PYTHONPATH` variables respectively for python2 and python3. If not, how can I add a library path exclusively to a particular version of python?

Comment: i had to use a `.pth` file: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53767029/52074

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can create a configuration file `mymodule.pth` under `lib/site-packages` (on Windows) or `lib/pythonX.Y/site-packages` (on Unix and Macintosh), then add one line containing the directory to add to python path.

From [docs.python2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/site.html) and [docs.python3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/site.html):

> > > A path configuration file is a file whose name has the form `name.pth` and exists in one of the four directories mentioned above; its contents are additional items (one per line) to be added to `sys.path`. Non-existing items are never added to `sys.path`, and no check is made that the item refers to a directory rather than a file. No item is added to `sys.path` more than once. Blank lines and lines beginning with # are skipped. Lines starting with `import` (followed by space or tab) are executed.

Answer (score 31):

`PYTHONPATH` is somewhat of a hack as far as package management is concerned. A "pretty" solution would be to *package* your library and *install* it.

This could sound more tricky than it is, so let me show you how it works.

Let us assume your "package" has a single file named `wow.py` and you keep it in `/home/user/mylib/wow.py`.

Create the file `/home/user/mylib/setup.py` with the following content:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(name="WowPackage",
      packages=["."],
)
```

That's it, now you can "properly install" your package into the Python distribution of your choice without the need to bother about `PYTHONPATH`. As far as "proper installation" is concerned, you have at least three options:

- "Really proper". Will copy your code to your python site-packages directory:

  ```
  $ python setup.py install
  ```
- "Development". Will only add a link from the python site-packages to `/home/user/mylib`. This means that changes to code in your directory will have effect.

  ```
  $ python setup.py develop
  ```
- "User". If you do not want to write to the system directories, you can install the package (either "properly" or "in development mode") to `/home/user/.local` directory, where Python will also find them on its own. For that, just add `--user` to the command.

  ```
  $ python setup.py install --user
  $ python setup.py develop --user
  ```

To remove a package installed in development mode, do

```
$ python setup.py develop -u
```

or

```
$ python setup.py develop -u --user
```

To remove a package installed "properly", do

```
 $ pip uninstall WowPackage
```

If your package is more interesting than a single file (e.g. you have subdirectories and such), just list those in the `packages` parameter of the `setup` function (you will need to list everything recursively, hence you'll use a helper function for larger libraries). Once you get a hang of it, make sure to read [a more detailed manual](https://pythonhosted.org/an_example_pypi_project/setuptools.html) as well.

In the end, go and contribute your package to PyPI -- it is as simple as calling `python setup.py sdist register upload` (you'll need a PyPI username, though).

Comment: This is similar to the `.pth` file solution in that we're adding something directly into the default directories.

Comment: Of course, that's how it is implemented on a low level. The benefit is in the use of a convenient higher-level abstraction, namely that of a "package", along with standard command-line interface.

Comment: I was just commenting on the two solutions. Making the custom library an actual library/package is also a good solution, and it will be the more appropriate one in many situations. It is cleaner, though not as fast and flexible as the `.pth` one.

Comment: don't forget the `__init__.py` even though python3 doesn't need it, when creating this pkg - it won't be able to import it later ... (at least for me)

Answer (score 2):

**I found that there is no way to modify `PYTHONPATH` that is only for `python2` or only for `python3`. I had to use a [`.pth` file](https://docs.python.org/3/library/site.html).**

What I had to do was:

- make sure directory is created in my home: `$HOME/.local/lib/python${MAJOR_VERSION}.${MINOR_VERSION}/site-packages`
- create a `.pth` file in that directory
- test that your `.pth` file is work
- done

For more info on `.pth. file syntax and how they work please see: [python2 docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/site.html) and [python3 docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/site.html).

(`.pth` files in a nutshell: when your python interpreter starts it will look in certain directories and see the `.pth` file, open those files, parse the files, and add those directories to your `sys.path` (i.e. the same behavior as `PYTHONPATH`) and make any python modules located on those directories available for normal importing.)

Comment: Hi Trevor thanks for the edit attempt but sadly syntax highlighting is not turned on yet in Space [Activate Language Sensitive Highlighting for code/script blocks?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/746/12102). Also I like to put the imports after the class and function definitions but before execution.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want to bother with moving/adding documents in `lib/site-packages`, try adding two lines of code in the python2.7 script you would like to run (below.)

```
import sys
sys.path = [p for p in sys.path if p.startswith(r'C:\Python27')]
```

This way, PYTHONPATH will be updated (ignore all python3.x packages) every time you run your code.

Comment: The hard-coded Windows default path is not portable, and won't be correct even on some Windows installations. Maybe inspect `sys.version` instead.